# Python Json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter:

Tags: python, json, string

I'm trying to load a dictionary into json but I'm getting error.

```
    strsdc = '''
```

{"ext":{"amznregion":["useast"],"someURL":"https://som_url.com/x/px/Iyntynt/{"c":"client","als2s":TIME}","id":"7788y"}}
'''
json.loads(strsdc)

gives me the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 187, in 
lol = json.loads(str(strsdc))
File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/json/**init**.py", line 357, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 2 column 79 (char 79)

Comment: What you've shown is neither a valid dictionary nor valid JSON

Comment: I'm grabbing it from a string using regex. What could I do to format this correctly so that it would work?

Comment: Maybe it's the regex that's wrong but we have no way of knowing as you haven't shown that

Answer (score 0):

Your json string is invalid.
I don't know if this is the way you want it but you can try using this string

```json
{"ext":{"amznregion":["useast"],"someURL":"https://som_url.com/x/px/Iyntynt/{\"c\":\"client\",\"als2s\":TIME}","id":"7788y"}}
```

Comment: thanks I tried this but it doesn't work if I turn this into a string using ''' {str}''' as the dict is in string format